# BigQuery user-defined function in JavaScript does not prune partitions

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that I'd like to partition by low-cardinality string column. That's not possible, so I have to hash strings into integer and partition by integer. I made a very naive hashing algorithm that converts those strings into integers between 0 and 100.

So far so good, I made a new table partitioned by this new integer field which is simply a function of another field. Now I can query this table by partitioned integer field and greatly reduce traffic. Cool! But I really want to query by the string field, so I made a user-defined function that basically does the hashing so I can write queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `partitioned_table` WHERE partitioned_int_field = HashOf("abc")
```

Which is essentially the same as this, but more performant:

```
SELECT * FROM `partitioned_table` WHERE unpartitioned_string_field = "abc"
```

Now the problem is, if I create user-defined function `HashOf` as SQL (just naive case-when, for example) it works just fine, the traffic reduces as expected. However, if I create the function as JavaScript (which is preferable here), then it has no effect on the traffic. The query works, but requires full table scan. Both SQL and JavaScript versions return exactly the same result, but JavaScript version doesn't prune partitions it seems like.

Am I missing something? Why JavaScript user-defined function does not prune partitions even though it returns the correct integer value for partitioned field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform your query in 2 step:

- First, calculate the hash field
- Second, query on the partitioned table with the calculated field

Something like this

```
DECLARE hhh INT64;

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getHash()
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  return 1;
""";

set hhh = (select getHash());

SELECT * FROM `gdglyon-cloudrun.dlp_test.number_partitioned` where num_partition=hhh;
```

It should work.

Comment: Doesn't help. It works exactly the same way: full-scan without partition pruning

Comment: I tested and the with works great without a function but failed (in fact perform a full scan) if a UDF is used. I successfully accomplish that with a script (updated in my answer

Comment: WIth `DECLARE` it works. Though usability suffers. Is this by design or is this some edge case? I mean calling UDF directly inside query

Comment: Agree, the usability is bad, but when you know the design of BigQuery, it's understandable: it can guess BEFORE the query run, what will be the partition to load. Because BigQuery need to run the query to interpret the UDF and to got that value. So, it loads all -> full scan